# Find View(like button) from text in Windows Phone 8 programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, ui-automation

i want to make an application in windows phone 8 that takes as input a String object and search the "view" to find if there is any view that has a title with that text(like a button with label "go") or from the id that i declared in the .xaml file. After this the goal is to find the view and to perform different actions like "click in a button, or write text in a Text Area) . Is that possible?

Comment: Looks like you're coming from Android. I'd recommend sticking to Windows Phone pattern instead of trying to implement Android pattern on Windows Phone. Can you tell us what is your goal, exactly?

Comment: well i am quite new at windows phone. as akshay2000 guessed i am coming from android. In android i have a tool that sends commands(via socket from pc to mobile) and an agent that accepts and "execute" this commands.in example i send < Button "test" press > string and the android "agent" taps in the button with label or id test that founds in the current view. My goal is to create a similar "automation agent" for windows phone. i just create a socket to receive commands but i dodn't know how to do the "automation part".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can do that using [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)'s GetChildrenCount and GetChild methods. In the class docs that I linked, you can see an example about traversing the visual tree. Just modify it to search for what you need.

Comment: i guess it's pretty new this feauture and it has Minimum supported Windows Phone 8.1. I don't believe i can try it in my windows phone 8.0 phone...

Comment: @simas Oh, my bad, I put the wrong link in there (it's fixed now). It is available, just in a different namespace. Edit: I can't say that you'll be able to do the automation, though. Some of these things can be done, but others - I'm not sure.

Comment: well i just tried... it recognizes the objects in the view..and then i can search button or text areas by the name.. So it's what i need! For the automation i tried some tap() or set text in edittext.. it seems to work! Thanks